# How to parse generic response using Codable

Tags: generics, codable

Every API have three parameters in the response.

1. `Code` : indicate whether API Success or fail(1 or 0)
2. `Message` : a string
3. `Data`: can be `Array` of object or single object.

i have created base model.

```
struct ResponseBase<T:Codable> : Codable {

    let code : String?
    let data : [T]
    let message : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code = "Code"
        case data = "Data"
        case message = "Message"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        code = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .code)
        data = try values.decodeIfPresent([T].self, forKey: .data)
        message = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .message)
    }
}

struct SocialWarmer : Codable {

    let createdDate : String?
    let lookUpId : String?
    let lookupKey : String?
    let lookupValue : String?
    let parentId : String?
    let statusFlag : String?
    let type : String?
    let updatedDate : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case createdDate = "CreatedDate"
        case lookUpId = "LookUpId"
        case lookupKey = "LookupKey"
        case lookupValue = "LookupValue"
        case parentId = "ParentId"
        case statusFlag = "StatusFlag"
        case type = "Type"
        case updatedDate = "UpdatedDate"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        createdDate = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .createdDate)
        lookUpId = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .lookUpId)
        lookupKey = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .lookupKey)
        lookupValue = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .lookupValue)
        parentId = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .parentId)
        statusFlag = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .statusFlag)
        type = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .type)
        updatedDate = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .updatedDate)
    }

}
```

Following is Code For API Request.

```
class BaseApiClient {

    static let `default`  = BaseApiClient()

    private init() {

    }

    func fetch<model:Codable>(request:APIRouter,decoder : JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()  ,onSuccess: @escaping ([model]) -> Void) {

        if Connectivity.isReachable {
            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).addProgressView()
            Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { (response) in
                switch response.result {
                case .success( let apiResponse) :
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).hideProgrssVoew()
                    }
                    if let responseData = apiResponse as? [String:Any] , let status  = responseData["Code"] as? String , status == "SUCCESS" {
                        do {
                            let responseModel  = try decoder.decode(ResponseBase<model>.self, from: response.data!)
                            onSuccess(responseModel.data!)
                        }
                        catch let error as NSError {
                            print("failed reason : \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        }

                        print(model.Type.self)
                        print(model.self)




                    }
                    else {
                        UIApplication.shared.gettopMostViewController()?.presentAlerterror(title: "Erorr", message: "Service not Avilabel" ,okclick: nil)
                    }
                case .failure(let error) :
                    UIApplication.shared.gettopMostViewController()?.presentAlerterror(title: "Erorr", message: error.localizedDescription, okclick: nil)
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).hideProgrssVoew()
            UIApplication.shared.gettopMostViewController()?.presentAlerterror(title: "Error", message: "connnection not avilabel", okclick: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

Following is code For calling API.

```
BaseApiClient.default.fetch(request: APIRouter.GetSocialWarmerType) { (response: [SocialWarmer]) in
    print(response)
}
```

But this model and API method will not work if data is single object.
What I am trying to achieve is to create single model and appropriate changes in API method that can parse both array of object and single object.

Comment: Unrelated, those `init(from:)` methods are unnecessary in your `Codable` types.

Comment: I’d also suggest just using Alamofire `response` rather than `responseJSON`. There’s no point in having Alamofire parse your JSON if you’re then going to parse it again.

Comment: You said that `Code` will "indicate whether API Success or fail(1 or 0)”. But you then define it to be a `String?`. Seems if it is 1 or 0, that it should be `Int`. I’m also unclear about the notion that all three types of `ResponseBase` are optionals? Are you not guaranteed that at least `Code` is always there?

Comment: Finally, I’d suggest that the generic only employ the constraint of `Decodable` (not `Codable`). In practice, it’s not likely to be a big deal, but `ResponseBase` doesn’t really care whether the type in the response can be both encoded and decoded. It only cares that it can be decoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response object should just use `T`, not `[T]`:

```
struct ResponseObject<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let code: String
    let data: T?
    let message: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code = "Code"
        case data = "Data"
        case message = "Message"
    }
}
```

Then, when you specify the type for the generic, that’s where you specify whether it is a single instance or an array.

For example, when you decode single instance, it is:

```
let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseObject<Foo>.self, from: data)
let foo = responseObject.data
```

But for an array, it is:

```
let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseObject<[Foo]>.self, from: data)
let array = responseObject.data
```

---

Here is a sample playground:

```
struct ResponseObject<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let code: String?
    let data: T
    let message: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code = "Code"
        case data = "Data"
        case message = "Message"
    }
}

struct Foo: Codable {
    let value: Int
}

do {
    let data = """
        {
            "Code": "some code",
            "Message": "some message",
            "Data": {
                "value": 42
            }
        }
        """.data(using: .utf8)!

    let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseObject<Foo>.self, from: data)
    let foo = responseObject.data
    print(foo)
} catch {
    print(error)
}

do {
    let data = """
        {
            "Code": "some code",
            "Message": "some message",
            "Data": [
                {
                    "value": 1
                }, {
                    "value": 2
                }, {
                    "value": 3
                }
            ]
        }
        """.data(using: .utf8)!

    let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseObject<[Foo]>.self, from: data)
    let array = responseObject.data
    print(array)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally I have Found one Workaround.i have Created two base class one for array of object and one for single object.

```
struct ResponseBaseArray<T:Codable> : Codable {

    let code : String?
    let data : [T]?
    let message : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code = "Code"
        case data = "Data"
        case message = "Message"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        code = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .code)
        data = try values.decodeIfPresent([T].self, forKey: .data)
        message = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .message)
    }
}


struct ResponseBaseObject<T:Codable> : Codable {

    let code : String?
    let data : T?
    let message : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code = "Code"
        case data = "Data"
        case message = "Message"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        code = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .code)
        data = try values.decodeIfPresent(T.self, forKey: .data)
        message = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .message)
    }
}
```

Following is Code For Api methods.

```
class BaseApiClient {

    static let `default`  = BaseApiClient()

    private init() {

    }

    func fetch<model:Codable>(request:APIRouter , decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder() ,onSuccess: @escaping (model) -> Void) {

        if Connectivity.isReachable {
            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).addProgressView()
            Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { (response) in
                switch response.result {
                case .success( let apiResponse) :

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).hideProgrssVoew()
                    }
                    if let responseData = apiResponse as? [String:Any] , let status  = responseData["Code"] as? String , status == "SUCCESS" {
                        do {
                            let responseModel  = try decoder.decode(model.self, from: response.data!)
                            onSuccess(responseModel)
                        }
                        catch let error as NSError {
                            print("failed reason : \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        UIApplication.shared.gettopMostViewController()?.presentAlerterror(title: "Erorr", message: "Service not Avilabel" ,okclick: nil)
                    }
                case .failure(let error) :
                    UIApplication.shared.gettopMostViewController()?.presentAlerterror(title: "Erorr", message: error.localizedDescription, okclick: nil)
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).hideProgrssVoew()
            UIApplication.shared.gettopMostViewController()?.presentAlerterror(title: "Error", message: "connnection not avilabel", okclick: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

Following is Code for Calling Api.

```
BaseApiClient.default.fetch(request: APIRouter.GetSocialWarmerType) { (rsult:ResponseBaseArray<[SocialWarmer]>) in
            print(rsult.data)
        }
```

if your Api return single object than use ResponseBaseObject.

```
BaseApiClient.default.fetch(request: APIRouter.GetSocialWarmerType) { (rsult:ResponseBaseObject<SocialWarmer>) in
            print(rsult.data)
        }
```

but still this solution will only work if you already know your Api will return single object or array of object.

Comment: "but still this solution will only work if you already know your Api will return single object or array of object” ... Any given endpoint should always an array or always a single instance. If you have in-house API that is changing the structure of the response based upon whether it found one result or many results, then you should fix that rather than coding clients around a poor web service design. Note, the generic, `ResponseBase`, should still be able to handle both types, though, but at the calling point, you should know the precise structure of the response.